# Are "yet" and "ever" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

I found this sentence in my textbook:

> "The motorcycle rider has done many amazing things in the past, but tomorrow he will try to pull off his most dangerous jump yet."

My dictionary says,"YET is used for saying that somebody or something is the most extreme ever." Then, can you also say " his most dangerous jump ever" instead of using "yet"in this sentence ?

Comment: "Yet" and "ever" are not synonyms -- but occasionally some of their uses overlap.  This is one such situation, but it doesn't mean the two words are *interchangeable*.

Comment: Journalists love saying *greatest ever* because it sounds so much more impressive than *greatest yet*.

Comment: If he didn't pull it off, and died, it would be his most dangerous jump ever.

Comment: "Ever" means "of all time". "Yet" means "so far". They do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

*yet* here means *till that time.* Simply put, tomorrow, the biker would try to put his best in that dangerous jump.

Don't we say, "He is yet to put his efforts in music"?

'Yet' can also be put at the end of the sentence - "I haven't told anyone else yet!"

---

(Note: the only thing I'm not sure in the sentence is the future tense)

Comment: You could also use 'so far" or 'to date"